# create a new gmail account for my google account after deleting the old one

Tags: gmail, google-account

I want to get rid of my current google gmail account under my current google account (the gmail account is a spam pit and has a dumb name) and use a brand new gmail account with my current google account. I don't care about transferring anything to the new gmail and I never want to use that gmail email again, I just don't want to have that email associated with my google account any longer.

I've searched online for answers to what my options are after deleting a gmail email account from your google account, but no one ever goes beyond the deletion step.

is it possible to create a new gmail email after deleting the old one?

***EDIT***

I can't jump to a new google account because I have family plans attached to my current account and tons of purchases that I don't want to lose

Comment: Could you be more specific about accounts, when referring to gmail account you mean a gmail.com account and google account means any G Suite with a personal domain account?

Comment: @MarioR. so google has two concepts of a "google account" one is with g-suite (which most would just call a g-suite account) and the other is a google account. when a person creates an email account with gmail, google automatically creates a google account in which the newly created gmail email will live under as well as any service you use from google (Fi, photos, drive, youtube, etc...). google tracks your account by the gmail email you created (since you can only have one at a time), but they also allow you to delete that gmail email as well

Comment: @MarioR. so I'm trying to figure out what are a user's options after they delete their gmail email from their google account. the internet seems to only have the same "how to delete" instructions regurgitate in different forms but nothing on what you can do after if you can create a new gmail email under your current google account